# ROS navigation warn: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map

Tags: ros, navigation, localization, rtabmap

Hi I am doing Navigation stack on pepper robot. while doing navigation stack I came across multiple warnings and errors. I rectified few warnings but facing other warnings too. I have searched on Google and other sources but unable to rectify the warning messages.  I am using rtabmap package for mapping and also for localization on ubuntu 16.04(ros-kinetic). here are the warnings that I got. [image] and also I have uploaded the all my files in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UvPPl_SprprtB77PQ-_6Q84phlfcoFgy?usp=sharing) with full console error/warning messages.

> [ WARN] [1708724408.189645929]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.100216 timeout was 0.1.
>
> [ WARN] (2024-02-23 22:40:09.298) Rtabmap.cpp:1257::process() Update map correction based on last localization saved in database! correction = xyz=3.720840,0.521860,0.000000 rpy=0.000000,-0.000000,-3.031832, nearest id = 1 of last pose = xyz=0.113425,0.062532,0.000001 rpy=0.001205,-0.000309,1.452687, odom = xyz=3.636022,0.061406,-0.000000 rpy=-0.000000,0.000023,-1.798667
>
> [ WARN] [1708724409.699125214]: Could not get transform from odom to base_link after 0,200000 seconds (for stamp=1708724409,292516)! Error="Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1708724409.292516015 but the earliest data is at time 1708724409.479435925, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]. canTransform returned after 0.200313 timeout was 0.2.".

> [ERROR] [1708724409.699208497]: Could not convert laser scan msg! Aborting rtabmapviz update...

and full console output is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bThV89IMEuvwE1WbFM-W8Rx4BeR4WIQV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please paste any console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....

Comment: My console output is very huge and unable to paste, as it is exceeding the word limit. But I already pasted my warning messages and error above. But [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bThV89IMEuvwE1WbFM-W8Rx4BeR4WIQV/view?usp=sharing) is the full console output.

Comment: What have you done to determine the cause of the laser scan error? by that I mean, have you confirmed the laser scan error is not the cuase of the warnings and then investigated?

Comment: I believe, the warnings are different and the error is different.